# Custom filling in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib for visualizing some data on a world map, and I would like to fill the regions with a custom pattern, which may be of multiple colors.

I have two main patterns that I would like to obtain:

1. fill each region with stripes, but those stripes have multiple colors and different thickness depending on the region. For example, one region may be totally red, another may be half red and half green, and another may have red and blue lines, but red lines are much thicker than the blue ones.
2. fill with different colors in a pie-chart sliced fashion: some rays depart from the centroid of the region toward the borders,

More generally, I would like to understand how to draw a custom image and use it as a repeated pattern. Each region I've got is a set of lines, so I can assume that I can compute its centroid, size and borders before drawing the pattern.

For example, I may want to draw an histogram for each region and plot the histogram inside the region, but for doing that I need a general way for using custom images as patterns.

So, how do I do that? I tried looking at matplotlib gallery, but didn't see anything like that.

EDIT: I saw the hatch demo, but as far as I understand, has just one color, and I cannot use custom images in it http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html

Comment: That example is using `bar()`, the function for bar charts. It only supports a single colour. It doesn't look like there is a simple way to do what you want. If I had to do it, I'd use imshow with colormaps from arrays created manually.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some hints. I'll try with images, colormaps and masks and see what I get.

Comment: Could not find a workaround. I ended up using matplotlib to compute the values, but cairo to draw.